# Why do we need an optional keyword OUTER in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

`LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` works exactly the same way.
Which means the keyword `OUTER` has no effect or it is *optional*.

Why do we include a keyword which has no effect in execution?

Comment: It is optional.

Comment: OUTER optional pointer { INNER | { { LEFT | RIGHT | FULL } [ OUTER ] } }

Comment: @a_hourse_with_no_name it is not a duplicate question. I know OUTER is optional. my point is that why do we include a keyword which has no effect in execution?

Comment: It's optional, it's included for ANSI-92 compatibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is optional, I always assumed that it was originally there as its more descriptive.

However it doesn't actually mean anything as a join is either inner, left, right or full - so the outer key word can be inferred to be relevant for all but inner joins.